# Webhook reponse data failing with 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, webhooks, shopify-app

I'm trying to get data from a Shopify Webhook when shopping cart is updated. It works up until I try to map the response I get.

It's showing the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

But if I console.log() the data, it is showing the array as it should. But still can't map() it.

```
async afterAuth(ctx) {
          ...
                const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
                ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
                    httpOnly: false,
                    secure: true,
                    sameSite: 'none'
                });
                await getSubscriptionUrl(ctx, accessToken, shop);

                const webhook = receiveWebhook({ secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY });

                router.post('/webhooks/carts/update', webhook, (ctx) => {

                    // This console log works
                    console.log(ctx.state.webhook);
                    
                    const cartProducts = ctx.state.webhook.payload.line_items.product_id;
                    
                    // This console log is not working = undefined
                    console.log('cartProducts: >>> ',cartProducts);

                    var productListIds = cartProducts.map(item => {
                        var product = item.product_id.toString();
                        return product
                    })
                    console.log('ARRAY OF PRODUCT IDS: ',productListIds);
                });
          ...
```

I expect the "cartProducts" to be available to use for map(). Will async/await help? If so, how do I implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you console.log(ctx) and what's the result in case you did?

Comment: @dshung1997 Thank you, it turned out I was trying to access empty data, because line_items have an array of items (product_id). So by removing the .product_id in the query it worked. Like the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the ***cartProducts*** variable as ***ctx.state.webhook.payload.line_items*** because only individual items have the *product_id* property.
You have tried to access the *product_id* property from the array before using the *map()* function.

```js
async afterAuth(ctx) {
    ...
    const {
      shop,
      accessToken
    } = ctx.session;
    ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none'
    });
    await getSubscriptionUrl(ctx, accessToken, shop);

    const webhook = receiveWebhook({
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY
    });

    router.post('/webhooks/carts/update', webhook, (ctx) => {

      // This console log works
      console.log(ctx.state.webhook);

      // Removed the 'product_id'
      const cartProducts = ctx.state.webhook.payload.line_items;

      console.log('cartProducts: >>> ', cartProducts);

      var productListIds = cartProducts.map(item => {
        var product = item.product_id.toString();
        return product
      })
      console.log('ARRAY OF PRODUCT IDS: ', productListIds);
    });
    ...
```